# unable to write echo output to a text file

Tags: php, echo, whitespace, fwrite

i want to generate random numbers twice say username and password and then want to save it in a text file. my script is generating numbers successfully but i am unable to put single white space between two variables also unable to write file in a text document. please find below my php script:

```
 /**
////generatePassword
**/
function generatePassword ($length = 7) 
{ 
  // start with a blank password 
  $genpassword = ""; 
  // define possible characters 
  $possible = "0123456789";  
  // set up a counter 
  $i = 0;  
  // add random characters to $password until $length is reached 
  while ($i < $length) {  
    // pick a random character from the possible ones 
    $char = substr($possible, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible)-1), 1); 
    // we don't want this character if it's already in the password 
    if (!strstr($genpassword, $char)) {  
      $genpassword .= $char; 
      $i++; 
    } 
  } 
  // done! 
  return $genpassword;}  



echo generatePassword().generatePassword();
$cfgclines='';
addFlinetoConfig($cfgclines);
writetoLog("cfgclines");
function addFlinetoConfig($cfgclines)
{$handle = fopen("/var/etc/user.cfg",'a');
fwrite($handle, $genpassword);
fclose($handle);
}

?>
```

when i open this file in a browser, i get random numbers like:
`83215063912640`
There should be a single white space after 7th characters like this:
`8321506 3912640`
Furthermore, i am unable to call echo function to write it on a text file named user.cfg

Answer (score 0):

Where you call `echo generatePassword().generatePassword()`, you need to manually add a space:

```
echo generatePassword() . " " . generatePassword();
```

As for your inability to write to the file, the code is correct, so there is likely a permission issue. Ensure that you give your script write access (the middle character of `chmod()`):

```
chmod("/var/etc/user.cfg", 0755);
```

Comment: your answer solved my 1st problem regarding space, but i am still unable to write it on a text file, permission is already corrected, however i have checked error log and found that entry in log file: ```PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: genpassword``` i think we have to define variable ```$genpassword``` first in php then call it in fwrite, but i don't know how to assign it as a $variable.